# While redrawing/panning the page in safari ipad/Iphone timer is not decreasing

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, ipad

I am facing one issue that in safari browser while dragging/moving the screening the javascript timer is not getting decreased. I have placed an alert message at the beginning of the function and I found that the function itself is not getting called.

So I am under such an impression that while repainting the screen in safari iphone/ ipad no javascript will work. Is it single threaded? how to achieve in safari ipad/iphone screen dragging and timer at the same time?

In Android while doing the same timer is actually getting decreased but not getting repainted. i.e. if for 15 seconds if I will drag the screen and the start time is 1.59 then while dragging it will show the time 1:59, but after stopping the dragging time automatically getting decreased by 15 seconds i.e. 1:44.

While investigating further I come across below document in developers.apple.com

"panning doesn’t generate any events until the user stops panning"

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

So now I think if We can create timer without events? Can I know the time-interval for which user is panning? 
How to achieve the same Android experience in safari iphone/ipad?